# Backbone.js slow server save() response overwrites locally changed attribute

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I've got some strange behavior going on with a Backbone model - attributes that I set between the time that I call `save()` and the server responds get thrown out, replaced by the server response (which just echos the saved attributes).

Is this the way Backbone is supposed to behave?  It's making my app look really insane when the server lags a bit - it overwrites my `currentScreen` attribute with the old one, which navigates backward a screen.  Here is my code:

```
Interview = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: "/interviews",
    defaults: {
        "currentScreen": 0
    }
});
```

and here's my Jasmine/Sinon.JS test describing what I expect (it fails with `Expected 0 to equal 1.`):

```
describe("Interview model", function() {

    beforeEach(function() {
        this.interview = new Interview;
    });

    describe("saving with a slow server response", function() {

        beforeEach(function() {
            this.server = sinon.fakeServer.create();
        });

        afterEach(function() {
            this.server.restore();
        });

        it('should not overwrite locally changed attributes on server response', function() {
            this.server.respondWith("PUT", "/interviews/1",
                       [200, { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
                        '{"id":1,"currentScreen":0}']);
            this.interview.set({id: 1, currentScreen: 0});
            this.interview.save();

            this.interview.set({currentScreen: 1}); // user navigates to next screen
            this.server.respond(); // return fake response after currentScreen changed locally
            expect(this.interview.get('currentScreen')).toEqual(1);
        });

    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is how it's supposed to work. Your server has the canonical set of data, so it overrides the client state with whatever the true value is.

If you don't want or need the server to update the client after a save, then simply don't return any changed attributes -- just use an empty object: `{}`

Comment: Thanks! My mistake was returning with `render :json => @interview` (Rails backend) which obviously returns all model attributes. I'm honored the Backbone creator answered my question. :-)